# Replicating ContextMenu constructor in ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

From my research and understanding, the ContextMenuStrip is supposed to be the successor to the ContextMenu and, in the spirit of keeping my code updated and sound, I set out to replace one such instance of a ContextMenu.

Previously, to give a MenuItem a sub-menu of items with click handlers, I was doing something like:

```
    MenuItem[] clearMenu = {    
                                new MenuItem("All", clear_all_click),
                                new MenuItem("Text", clear_text_click),
                                new MenuItem("Images", clear_images_click),
                                new MenuItem("Audio", clear_audio_click) 
                           };

    notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Clear", clearMenu));
```

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple, but how do I achieve similar functionality with a ContextMenuStrip? There is no overloaded constructor for the ToolStripMenuItem that lets you add an array of itself to form a sub-menu. There also isn't a way to add items based on selecting a specific item index from the ContextMenuStrip, like:

```
 notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items["Clear"].Add
```

There is a constructor that let's you instantiate, presumably, a sub-menu with an array of ToolStripItem(s), but it's an abstract class so you can't call it directly.

Thoughts? Or am I not seeing the forest through the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you want.  But to access via keyname, you must set the name:

```
ToolStripItem[] newItems = {
                    new ToolStripMenuItem("All", null, DoThis),
                    new ToolStripMenuItem("Text", null, DoThis)
                };

this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Clear", null, newItems) {Name="Clear"});

var clearItem = this.contextMenuStrip1.Items["Clear"] as ToolStripMenuItem;
```